# How to add annotation for errors in @monaco-editor/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I am using @monaco-editor/react component as JavaScript code editor in my application.
The editor underlines the errors, but I want the editor to add an exclamation mark in front of line numbers as well.

How can I achieve that?